# Custom post Type, child of a Page?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, child-pages

I have a list of products: they're split into different "categories". For example:

- Subcompact Cars
- Racing Cars

Then, I have other sub-categories, like this:

- Subcompact Cars

--- 4-doors

--- 5-doors

- Racing Cars

--- 4-doors

--- 5-doors

Each car is a Custom Post Type, but the tree that is composing this logic is made of PAGES and not of Archives. I have a page for Subcompact cars, a page for Subcompact cars 4-doors, a page for subcompact cars 5-doors etc...
It's done this way because each page is different and has specific rules that couldn't be achieved via Archive page.
In the final step, the user arrives to the custom post type (ex. "Mercedes"), but since it's a CPT it doesn't have a relation to the page that should be its parent, for example ***Subcompact Cars > 5-Doors***. I want to have this relationship (so, between the CPT and a Page) and I want to have the exact breadcrumb in the CPT. (ex. ***Subcompact Cars > 5-Doors > Mercedes***)

I have tried with the "Relation" Advanced Custom Type, but I can't find a way to generate the Breadcrumb in the final page (the CPT). Also, i'd like the URl to reflect this behaviour, so if the final PAGE is "*mydomain.com/subcompact-cars/5doors*" I'd like to have "*mydomain.com/subcompact-cars/5-doors/mercedes*" as final URL.

I've never done something this way, and It's driving me crazy. I can't touch the other pages (I would have used a hierarchical category style instead of custom pages) because I don't have much time and I'm working on a website made by others. I have to find a way out.

Thank you!

PS. It would be no problem for me if I had to copy-paste the URL of the parent page into an Advanced Custom Field, that would be fine too. But I **have** to generate the correct breadcrumb and I possibly have to generate the exact url.

Comment: Have a look at  [Pods Framework](http://pods.io/). This might be a more comfortable solution for your requirements.

Comment: Currently with ACF I already have the opportunity to set a relationship between the post and the page, but I don't know how to handle it and generate the breadcrumb!